# sculpt widget sticking on surface

Tags: 3d-view, sculpting

today I was wondering why every sculpting app has the circle widget sticking to the surface normal and Blender does not, I find it to be a quite important visual aid

Retopoflow addon's widget does it already but, as far as I know, there is no sculpting plugin with a similar widget, and don't know if this functionality can be extracted from it being working modal.
Is this sort of widget feature be even tackled by an addon (if it doesn't exist already)?

Blender it's already a really powerful tool for sculpting and 2.77 improvement are great, maybe it's just me feeling this need?

Comment: I am sure more than one person has done the work, I can recall seeing more than one demo video of it working. The only reference I can find now is a 5 year old [GSOC proposal](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Jwilkins/GSoC2011/Google_Summer_of_Code_2011_Preliminary_Documentation) Cannot say why it hasn't made it into a release.

Comment: thanks I didn't know about this GSOC, hopefully someone will have the interest (and skill) to finish it one day.